# How to implement download function in web view for google drive files?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, google-drive-android-api

Hi I am developing an application in which I have provided google drive link so user can download file from there but on clicking download button from the drive file starts to download but not anything download happens. Here I using this code check and either toast is not working please help

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);

            Toast.makeText(BPhOneWeb.this,"Downloadig started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    });
```